# Multiple List Object only can add single item to preceding lists? First list works

Tags: c#, .net

Multiple List Object only can add single item to preceding lists.  Only adds last item for second list and of course I need all of them not just the last one.

Here is my Code:

```
public class MyListData
{
    public List<HeaderItem> HeaderItems { get; set; }
    public List<MatrixItem> MatrixItems { get; set; }
}
public MyListData GetSchedule()
{
    MyListData objTab = new MyListData();
    objTab.HeaderItems = new List<HeaderItem>();

    //Header loop works perfectly
    for(int x=0; x < 7;x++)
    {
        HeaderItem objItem = new HeaderItem();
        objItem.strHeadName = x;
        objTab.HeaderItems.Add(objItem);
    }

    objTab.MatrixItems = new List<MatrixItem>();
    for(int x=0; x < 7;x++)
    {
        MatrixItem objItem = new MatrixItem();
        objItem.nHRJobID = x;
        objTab.MatrixItems.Add(objItem);
    }

    //Only adds the last one Need ALL

    return objTab;
}
```

If I need to create a new object then how would I combine say objTab and objMatrix?

Comment: Also what does `HeaderItem` and `MatrixItem` look like? At first glance, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong. Why do you think only the last item was added? What's `objTab.MatrixItems.Count` after the loop?

Comment: Ok - I notice when I edited that you where using typed lists, just the <pre> tag was hiding them. Don't use the <pre> tag in your questions. SO will format your code if you indent it.

Comment: Its adds items without issue the only problem is it will only add one item and its overwriting the previous values and only returning a single item.

Comment: So was thinking I need to create MyListData objMatrix = new MyListData();  but then how to I combine objTab and objMatrix, not merge, not copy.

Comment: No it doesn't. It works [just fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BrgU24). You have something else going on that you are not showing us and, as such, your question is unanswerable. Your code will add 7 `MatrixItem`s each with a different `nHRJobID`.

Comment: what you are saying is that it adds 7 items to headeritems but only adds 1 to matrixitems?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to add all seven values for both HeaderItem and MatrixItem, based on the code you shared.

If you want to combine the header and Matrix item into a single list you might use a Tuple<> instead of a nested class. I've created a sample of what that would look like and included the code I used to test your sample code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace listadd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Original GetSchedule:");
            MyListData mld = GetSchedule();
            for (int i = 0; i < mld.HeaderItems.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("HeaderItem: {0}, MatrixItem: {1}", mld.HeaderItems[i].strHeadName, mld.MatrixItems[i].nHRJobID));
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Tuple GetSchedule:");
            var list = GetScheduleCombined();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("HeaderItem: {0}, MatrixItem: {1}", list[i].Item1.strHeadName, list[i].Item2.nHRJobID));
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("combined GetSchedule:");
            var clist = GetScheduleCombined2();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("HeaderItem: {0}, MatrixItem: {1}", clist[i].hdrItm.strHeadName, clist[i].mtxItm.nHRJobID));
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static List<Tuple<HeaderItem, MatrixItem>> GetScheduleCombined()
        {
            List<Tuple<HeaderItem, MatrixItem>> list = new List<Tuple<HeaderItem, MatrixItem>>();
            for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
            {
                var h = new HeaderItem();
                h.strHeadName = x;
                var m = new MatrixItem();
                m.nHRJobID = x;
                list.Add(new Tuple<HeaderItem, MatrixItem>(h, m));
            }
            return list;
        }

        public class MyCombined
        {
            public MyCombined()
            {
                hdrItm = new HeaderItem();
                mtxItm = new MatrixItem();
            }
            public HeaderItem hdrItm { get; set; }
            public MatrixItem mtxItm { get; set; }
        }
        public static List<MyCombined> GetScheduleCombined2()
        {
            List<MyCombined> list = new List<MyCombined>();
            for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
            {
                var item = new MyCombined();
                item.hdrItm.strHeadName = x;
                item.mtxItm.nHRJobID = x;
                list.Add(item);
            }
            return list;
        }

//----- begin original sample code from question -----
        public class MyListData
        {
            public List<HeaderItem> HeaderItems { get; set; }
            public List<MatrixItem> MatrixItems { get; set; }
        }

        public static MyListData GetSchedule()
        {
            MyListData objTab = new MyListData();
            objTab.HeaderItems = new List<HeaderItem>();

            //Header loop works perfectly
            for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
            {
                HeaderItem objItem = new HeaderItem();
                objItem.strHeadName = x;
                objTab.HeaderItems.Add(objItem);
            }

            objTab.MatrixItems = new List<MatrixItem>();
            for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
            {
                MatrixItem objItem = new MatrixItem();
                objItem.nHRJobID = x;
                objTab.MatrixItems.Add(objItem);
            }

            //Only adds the last one Need ALL

            return objTab;

        }
// ---- End original sample code ----
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd rather just create a class that holds a `HeaderItem` and a `MatrixItem` rather than use a `Tuple`. `Tuple` is good for quick and dirty, but ultimately you are probably better off with a class with a `Header` and `Matrix` property rather than `Item1` and `Item2`.

Comment: I chose a Tuple because the sample was quick and dirty and only had two items. I agree, Item1 and Item2 are a bit generic and the use of a Class is more readable in a larger application.